# How to display select options in mobile as same as desktop view?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, responsive-design, html-select

I've been trying to figure out how to display select options like the desktop browser. This is how I want to display in all devices:

[image: Desktop dropdown view]

I tried to check if it was displayed as the same on the mobile, so I chose iPhone as a device and tried inspection. It was displayed correctly:

[image: chrome inspection view]

However, I tried to open it in a simulator and this was the result:

[image: simulator view]

I have tried `appearance: "none"`, but it didn't prevent the mobile version of the dropdown. It wasn't specific to the iPhone or the browser. The result was the same for the Android simulator and the chrome browser in it. My code was similar to the below one.

```
return (
<div>
  <select multiple style={{ width: 100, appearance: "none", "-moz-appearance": "none", "-webkit-appearance": "none" }}>
    {[1,2,3,4,5].map(number => <option>{number}</option>)}
  </select>
</div>
);
```

My question is how can I prevent this from happening on mobile devices without a workaround like a dropdown that consists of semantic elements?

Comment: If you don't mind using JQuery, consider Select2 https://select2.org/

Comment: That is the default behaviour of the browsers in mobile. For accessibility reasons you should choose default browser behaviour over the other.